# Make CapsLock switch between text input and navigation

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard-layout

I'd prefer <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to switch between text and navigation modes rather than lowercase and uppercase modes, much like <kbd>NumLock</kbd> swaps numbers and navigation, on as low a level as possible.

For example, I'd like <kbd>i</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> keys to send <kbd>Up</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> signals whenever CapsLock is “on”. How to achieve this, in both console and X?

Comment: write a keyboard driver. or get very intimate with `setkeycodes` and friends.

Comment: @mikeserv I don't see how I can do this with `setkeycodes`. It maps scancodes to keycodes, so it looks like I should assign arrow keycodes to scancodes corresponding to `CapsLock`'ed letters. However, `showkey --scancodes` shows me identical scancodes for, say, Capsed `i` keypress and the plain one.

Comment: thats only the beginning. your input is interrupted in a hundred different ways on down the line - and starting and sourcing from the kernel. thats where you begin.

Comment: I recommend splitting, or at least [edit]ing, this question.  Doing this for _both_ the kernel virtual terminals and for the X server would involve two different subsystems.  I suspect that you are only actually interested in the X case.

Comment: @JdeBP I'm afraid what I wanted was a uniform solution across the OS. Actually, I believe the correct answer is found in comments already: that there simply is no uniform way to achieve this, because X and tty handle keyboard input independently. I'd say this is not obvious and would accept the answer that makes it clear. I'd also restrict the question to Linux explicitly, since if the solution is ever to come, it's going to be on implemented on the kernel level, but for some reason Save Edits button is disabled. (Too small a change?)